# How to measure search query and hits?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have a page with search functionality and would like to use Google Analytics to measure both the search query/term and the number of hits found. What would be the best way of doing that?

Example:

If a user searches for "Football" and gets 32 results, I want to store both "Football" and "32", and be able to create reports like this:

```
# | Word | Number of searches | Total hits | Average number of hits
1 | Football | 3 | 96 | 32
2 | Basketball | 2 | 12 | 6
3 | Snowboard | 6 | 6 | 1
```

I have looked into [custom dimensions and metrics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/custom-dims-mets), but it's not clear to me how to actually achieve what I want.

Any help and example code would be much appreciated.

Remi

---

**Solution:**

```
function measureSearchResult(query, hits) {
    if (query) {
        ga('send', 'event', {
            'eventCategory': 'Search',
            'eventAction': 'Hits',
            'eventLabel': query,
            'eventValue': hits,
            'hitCallback': function () {
                console.log('*** Google Analytics - search logged: "' + query + '", ' + hits + ' hits');
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could capture the number of results as an event and then put together a customized report to reflect what you are trying to achieve.

I am not aware on what type of language you are using and how you'd exactly code it, but for Google Analytics to see the event, you'd use something like:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Search', 'Hits', '','value']);
```

Or if you do not want to add a value, you could populate the third one with the number instead.

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Search', 'Hits', 'value-here-instead']);
```

The anatomy of event tracking in the example above, would capture an event where it has Category set to Search, Action set as Hits and its label would be set to the value you have.

Please note that the example above is for the Classic Analytics, ga.js, and doesn't work with Universal Analytics, analytics.js. The syntax is slightly different, but the idea stays the same.

Comment: while using event tracking to track site search probably would work. Mind you its not going to come under the site search reports then its going to come under the event reports.  It seams like a bit of over kill when you could just enable site search in Google Analytics.

Comment: That is true. I assumed though that site search was actually already in effect which might have been an error. What I wanted to achieve was a way to be able to extract the # of results for each search, that in turn was captured through site search, and then through events. Then one could have made a custom report to detail the metrics needed for the keywords used.

Comment: Thanks! This seems to solve my problem. Lets hope its possible to produce reasonable reports as well :)

Answer (score 2):

You could enable the `site search` in your google analytics account.

You can find it under admin -> View (profile) -> view settings -> site search settings.

You will need to enable it and tell it what the query parameter is for your sight.

https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/1321536?hl=en

Once you have done that you will be able to Track the search terms used as visits and page views in the  `Behavior -> site search -> usage` reports.   Just remember its going to take about 24 hours before you will be able to see the Site search data in these reports after you enable it.

---

Update in response to comment below

If you are using Univrsal analytics you can log it as a custom dimension.  Which is probably the best way of going.  @mrSponge's solution uses eventTracking and his example of event tracking isn't using Universal analytics.  I sugest you figure out first if you are runing Clasic analytics or Universal Analytics.  Then you can decided which option will be better suited to your needs.    I have a short tutorial on Custom Dimensions here http://www.daimto.com/custom-dimensions-and-metrics/

Fastest way to tell if you are running Clasic analytics or Universal analytics is to search for `.push`  if you see that then your running classic analytics.  If your analytics tracking code starts with **UA-** then you could run universal analytics you just need to change from using the ga.js to the analytics.js code in your site.

If your intersted in checking out the event tracking for universal analytics you can read about it here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events

Comment: Thanks. 

Unfortunately, i'm not using a parameter based search, so as far as I can see this will not be possible with your solution.

I'm creating a SPA with Durandal.js, so the closest to query parameters will maybe be the hash based routing?

Comment: If you are using Univrsal analytics you can log it as a custom dimension.  Which is probably the best way of going.  @mrSponge's solution uses eventTracking and his example of event tracking isnt using Universal analytics.  I sugest you figure out first if you are runing Clasic analytics or Universal Analytics.  Then you can decided which option will be better suited to your needs.

Comment: I'm using Universal Analytics.

Comment: then you should be able to follow the tutorial above on how to create a new custom dimension in your Analtyics account.   then it will simply be a case of adding ga('set','dimension1','<searchString>');    Just remember to make sure you have the right dimension number